# Filling out a cheque - 金

Tags: kanji, numbers

I'm watching a drama and there's a scene with a closeup of a cheque. It shows the box where you would write the amount to pay, which I've parsed as below. What is `金` used for and how is it read? `金額` already specifies it's an amount of money plus there are two different yen symbols used.

> 金額 ￥ 金壱億伍阡萬円也

=

> 金額・￥・金・壱億伍阡萬・円・也

=

> (amount)・(yen symbol)・**(?)**・(一億五千万)・(another yen symbol)・(exact amount / "only")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing "金" at the beginning of numbers such as monetary amounts is to prevent altering or falsification. Possible altering is to add another number before the digit string. Therefore, it is important not to leave a gap between "金" and the beginning of the numbers so that not any numbers are added.

Further more, we use "壱, 弐, 参, 拾, 阡, 萬 and 圓" instead of "一, 二, 三, 十, 千, 万, and 円" respectedly in order to prevent altering.
They used "円" in the example given by OP, but we usually use "圓" for "円".

I think you can easily understand that "一", "二" and "三" are easily altered into "五".
"十", "千" and "万" could be changed into "五", too.

Answer (score 2):

This type of 金 is a prefix that just indicates the following number is an amount of money. It's read as きん. For example, 金三万円 (read きん さんまんえん) means "30,000 yen (of money)". This is occasionally used in certain serious financial contexts, particularly in places where [大字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals#Formal_numbers) are still used.

Practically, the only chance for a layperson to write this type of 金 is when they prepare money envelopes such as [祝儀袋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%ABgi-bukuro). See [how to prepare 祝儀袋](https://wedding.rakuten.co.jp/guest/goshugi/writing/) (in Japanese). The majority of Japanese people have never seen nor used checks in Japan.